# How can I setup Power BI Report Builder to an Excel Data Connection and retrieve the data from a Table

Tags: excel, xml, powerbi, connection-string, reportbuilder

I am new to Power BI Report Builder and I am trying to setup an Excel spreadsheet as a Data Source.  I'm not quite sure on the Connection String, so any help on that would be a great start.  But I really don't have a clue how to build a query to specify the data I want from the Data Source.  When I try it gives me the error message "The XmlDP query is invalid".  I haven't used XmlDP before so I don't know what I should be writing.

In the Excel spreadsheet, I have a table called "Table_Calendar", in Sheet2.  I want to pick up all columns in this table and all rows.  Please help!

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

[image: Report Builder Connection String]

[image: Report Builder Query Data]

Comment: follow the steps explained here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-excel

Comment: Hi. That talks about Power BI Desktop, this one I'm using is not Power BI Desktop it's "Report Builder".